# Why does electron gives access violation trying to access a new Isolate?

Tags: javascript, c++, electron, node.js-addon

I wrote a Node.js addon to be used in Electron framework
The main entry of the addon calls another C++ library that makes a long running operation so I put callbacks in to have reports of the operation progress.
So the C++ library calls a callback in my addon but the Isolate is null so I tried to create a new one
The isolate is created well but when I try to use it to have new Local i had this error:

> Exception thrown at 0x0000000000000000 in electron.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x0000000000000000.

Here is an excerpt of my code (the `progress_cb` variable takes value in the main entry of the addon casting the function passed in Javascript call):

```
Local<Function> progress_cb;

class ArrayBufferAllocator : public ArrayBuffer::Allocator {
public:
    virtual void* Allocate(size_t length) {
        void* data = AllocateUninitialized(length);
        return data == NULL ? data : memset(data, 0, length);
    }
    virtual void* AllocateUninitialized(size_t length) { return malloc(length); }
    virtual void Free(void* data, size_t) { free(data); }
};

void progress_callback(int read, int write, int total)
{
    V8::Initialize();
    ArrayBufferAllocator allocator;
    Isolate::CreateParams params;
    params.array_buffer_allocator = &allocator;
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    if (!isolate) {
        isolate = Isolate::New(params);
        isolate->Enter();
    }
    const unsigned argc = 3;
    Local<Integer> r = Int32::New(isolate, (int32_t)read);
    Local<Integer> w = Int32::New(isolate, (int32_t)write);
    Local<Value> t = Int32::New(isolate, (int32_t)total);
    Local<Value> argv[argc] = { r, w, t };
    progress_cb->Call(isolate->GetCurrentContext()->Global(), argc, argv);
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: It looks like your `progress_callback` is being called when execution control is not inside of your addon. e.i. javascript calls main function of your addon, inside of it you call another C++ library registering callbacks and return control to javascript, then at some point callback is called by that another C++ library in another thread.

Comment: @VTT you are right but I need this callback to not block the UI of my Electron app. So when I am in the addon callback (`progress_callback`) the Isolate is null and I need to create a new, but the `isolate = Isolate::New(params)` is correctly executed and a new Isolate is created but I cannot use it to create a new `Int32` value. Is there any other procedure to correctly instantiate a new Isolate?

Comment: One does never need to create a new Isolate. You just need to implement callback properly: either by adding polling javascript method or by hooking into javascript event loop.

Comment: Can you show me or link an example, please?

Comment: For example [Node.js Addons Part 4 - Asynchronous addons](https://nodeaddons.com/c-processing-from-node-js-part-4-asynchronous-addons/)

Comment: Did you find answer for this?